# Map Cassandra table Query results to C# Objects

Tags: c#, cassandra, datastax

Is there a builtin way in DataStax C# Driver for Apache Cassandra to map the ResultSet coming from a BoundStatement to the domain objects C# classes?
I am reading from a table and query is dynamic based on some variables, Not reading all columns in the query and mapping results to an Object

```
        switch (language)
        {
            case "en-GB":
                sql ="select col1id,col2id,col3id,descriptions_en,col2description_en,col3iddescription_en  from product_by_cols";           
            break;
            case "nb-NO":
                sql ="select col1id,col2id,col3id,descriptions_nb,col2description_nb,col3iddescription_nb  from product_by_cols";
            break;
            case "nn-NO":
                sql ="select col1id,col2id,col3id,descriptions_bn,col2description_bn,col3iddescription_nn  from product_by_cols";
            break; 
        }
        var ps = Service.Session.Prepare(sql);
        // Disable automatic paging.
        var statement = ps
           .Bind()
           .SetAutoPage(false)
           .SetPageSize(pageSize ?? 500);
        if (pageState != null && pageState.Length > 0)
        {
            statement.SetPagingState(Convert.FromBase64String(pageState));
        } 
        
        // Execute a query on a connection synchronously
        var rs =await Service.Session.ExecuteAsync(statement);
        // Store the paging state         
        List<CustomProduct> dbProducts = new List<CustomProduct>();
        // Iterate through the RowSet
        foreach (var row in rs)
        {
            dbProducts.Add(new CustomProduct
            {
                Col1Descriptions = row.GetValue<string>("descriptions_en"),
                Col1Id = row.GetValue<int>("col1id"),
                Col2Description = row.GetValue<string>("col2description_en"),
                Col2Id = row.GetValue<int>("col2id"),                    
                Col3Description = row.GetValue<string>("col3iddescription_en"),
                Col3Id = row.GetValue<int>("col3id")
            });
        }

        return new PagedResultWrapper<ICollection<CustomProduct>>(pageSize ?? 500,
         rs.PagingState,dbProducts );
```

Is there any way to map the rowset directly to CustomProduct Also not sure does the current approach have any perfomance impact when dealing with large record set

I found Cassandra.Mapping.Mappings to map the Cassandra tables directly to C# objects , but in my case i have to map columns of a cassandra table dynamically to a custom class object

Comment: You say you found Cassandra.Mapping.Mappings but that wouldn't work for your use case but I'm failing to understand why? It seems to be a good use case for it?

Comment: What  i have to do is map only few columns from a table to an Object , Not all the columns  Like col1desc_en or col1desc_nb or col1dec_nn value of the column as col1desc.  As you can see based on a querystring , the select query will vary . Not sure Cassandra.Mapping.Mappings will work in this case

Comment: You can choose which columns are mapped to which properties of a C# class, it should work for your use case: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.16/features/components/mapper/

Comment: Can i do a mapping of multiple columns to a single property in this case ?For<CustomClassObj>()
        .TableName("table_by_col")         
        .PartitionKey(new string[] { "col2id" })             
         .Column(u => u.col1desc, cm => cm.WithName("col1desc_en"))
          .Column(u => u.col1desc, cm => cm.WithName("col1desc_nb"))
          .Column(u => u.col1desc, cm => cm.WithName(col1desc_nn));

Comment: I don't think so but you can set multiple mappings for the same table I believe so you could just write different classes and mappings for different columns on the same table.

Comment: Yes this will solve my problem i guess. I was not aware that it is possible to add multiple mappings for the same table.